# Mingw compilation error using

Tags: c++, random, std

Trying to get the example at the bottom of [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) cppreference page to run. I have modified it so that it doesn't use `std::random_device` which is not available on mingw. The exact code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 gen();
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1, 2);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Compile errors can be found at http://pastebin.com/hekFJ44G (expires in 1 month). Anyone know a work around? I tried combing through the source but I can't understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modified the example to remove `std::random_device`, you changed:

```
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
```

which declares a object of type `std::mt19937` named `gen` to:

```
std::mt19937 gen();
```

which is an instance of the dreaded "[most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)", so `gen` is a function declaration instead of a declaration of an `mt19937` object.

Change that line of code to: `std::mt19937 gen;`